# Docker-compose Rails backend + postgresql could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, port

whenever I run the two containers (with docker-compose or individually, postgres first), the moment the backend container runs the db:create (via instruction `RUN RAILS_ENV=production bin/rails db:create && RAILS_ENV=production bin/rails db:migrate` in its Dockerfile or via CLI `rails db:create` when running the dangling image interactively) I have this message in the terminal:

```
could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known
Couldn't create 'pia_production' database. Please check your configuration.
```

Here is my docker-compose yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    build: ./db/
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: always  
    expose:
      - "5432"
    ports:
      # exposed port:postgres port
      - "5432:5432"
    env_file: 
      - ./db/.env
    # these environment variables should be defined in the .env file
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      PG_DATA: ${PG_DATA}
    networks:
      - my-network

  back:
    build: ./pia-rails/
    volumes:
      - ./logs/:/home/adminpia/pia-back/log/
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    links:
      - db:db
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - my-network
    env_file: 
      - ./pia-rails/.env

networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge
```

I have verified the start order, I have tried wait-for-it (github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it.git) and a script of my own:

```
#!/bin/bash
a=0
t=0
while ((a < 1))
        do
t=$(( t + 1 ))
        echo -ne "No process on port 5432, waiting $t s for postgresql...\r"
        echo -ne "\b\b"
        sleep 1s
        b=$(netstat -tulpn | grep 5432)
        if [ ! -z "$b" ]
        then
                a=1
                echo "A process is listening on 5432, presuming postgresql"
                exit 0
        fi
done
```

which I know it's redundant info since running docker-compose up db and then the backend produces the same outcome.

I've looked for answers here but found none regarding Rails+posgresql specifically and none which wasn't resolved by waiting for the postgresql container to be listening on port 5432 (after configuring the port obviously).

db image: Postgres:12-alpine
backend image: ruby 2.7.0, rails 6.0.3.4, uname -a:

```
Linux 8e59808d6845 5.4.0-52-generic #57~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 15 14:04:49 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Docker version 19.03.13, build 4484c46d9d

In reply to @3DPrintScanner, I can see my db container :

```
     Name                    Command              State    Ports
----------------------------------------------------------------
cnildocker_db_1   docker-entrypoint.sh postgres   Exit 0
```

but it doesn't seem to be using the 5432 port even though `docker run -p 5432:5432 --env-file ./.env -v PG_DATA -it postgres:12-alpine` on its own seems to work properly:

```
PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.

2020-11-02 13:12:04.054 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.0 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 9.3.0) 9.3.0, 64-bit
2020-11-02 13:12:04.055 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2020-11-02 13:12:04.056 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2020-11-02 13:12:04.060 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2020-11-02 13:12:04.066 UTC [45] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-11-02 13:12:03 UTC
2020-11-02 13:12:04.075 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Here is my database.yml from the backend image:

```
development:
  adapter:  postgresql
  host:     db
  encoding: unicode
  database: pia_development
  pool:     5
  username: 
  password:
  template: template0

test:
  adapter:  postgresql
  host:     db
  encoding: unicode
  database: pia_test
  pool:     5
  username:
  password:
  template: template0

production:
  adapter:  postgresql
  host:     db
  encoding: unicode
  database: pia_production
  pool:     5
  username: pia
  password: #{PIA_PWD}
  template: template0
```

Comment: What is the contents of the Dockerfile in `./db/` ? Can you check whether the container is running with `docker-compose ps `? Can you use the basic postgres image instead? Can you also add the contents of `database.yml`?

Comment: Yes @3DPrintScanner I can see it in docker-compose ps (see the edited question for details)

Comment: Why build the postgres container rather than getting the default container?

Comment: @TheGeorgeous Originally there were other actions I was going to have to perform in its Dockerfile